# How to plot corresponding values of multiple pairwise data frames in a single graph?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

Consider two pairwise dataframes such as follows:

```
diff1<- structure(list(X = structure(c(56L, 35L, 36L, 33L), .Label = c("t1", 
"t10", "t11", "t12", "t13", "t14", "t15", "t16", "t17", "t18", 
"t19", "t2", "t20", "t21", "t22", "t23", "t24", "t25", "t26", 
"t27", "t28", "t29", "t3", "t30", "t31", "t32", "t33", "t34", 
"t35", "t36", "t37", "t38", "t39", "t4", "t40", "t41", "t42", 
"t43", "t44", "t45", "t46", "t47", "t48", "t49", "t5", "t50", 
"t51", "t52", "t53", "t54", "t55", "t56", "t57", "t58", "t59", 
"t6", "t60", "t61", "t62", "t63", "t64", "t7", "t8", "t9"), class = "factor"), 
t6 = c(0, NA, NA, NA), t40 = c(0.188, 0, NA, NA), t41 = c(0.19, 
0.022, 0, NA)), .Names = c("X", "t6", "t40", "t41"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")


dist1<- structure(list(X = structure(c(56L, 35L, 36L, 33L), .Label = c("t1", 
"t10", "t11", "t12", "t13", "t14", "t15", "t16", "t17", "t18", 
"t19", "t2", "t20", "t21", "t22", "t23", "t24", "t25", "t26", 
"t27", "t28", "t29", "t3", "t30", "t31", "t32", "t33", "t34", 
"t35", "t36", "t37", "t38", "t39", "t4", "t40", "t41", "t42", 
"t43", "t44", "t45", "t46", "t47", "t48", "t49", "t5", "t50", 
"t51", "t52", "t53", "t54", "t55", "t56", "t57", "t58", "t59", 
"t6", "t60", "t61", "t62", "t63", "t64", "t7", "t8", "t9"), class =  "factor"), 
t6 = c(0, NA, NA, NA), t40 = c(0.0584765062354, 0, NA, NA
), t41 = c(0.0584765062354, 0.006363866564, 0, NA)), .Names = c("X", 
"t6", "t40", "t41"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I can easily plot the corresponding values from the two dataframes in a single plot. But I have multiple "diff" and multiple "dist" dataframes with the exact same structure and I don't know how I can integrate all correponding values in a single plot?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more on what you want?

Comment: why are you plotting distance matrix in ggplot?

Comment: What is your alternative?

Comment: @J.Con Well, I have big pairs of csv files that have exact same row and column names and I need to plot corresponding values from all pairs on a single plot

Comment: Okay, but what sort of plot? Can you provide the example of what you have already done with these two data frames?